# Calculating data of individual cells of EditText type and display result in TextView type in the corresponding cell

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a basic android app since I'm a beginner. I created a dynamic table with 4 columns as: Serial number, width, length and the area of width and length entered.
But I'm not understanding how to calculate result at the same time and display in the cell of fourth column as the user is entering the data in the respective fields.
Here is the java code that I've come up with so far:

```
    TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);
    TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);

    TableRow.LayoutParams r1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(180, 50);

    tv0.setTextSize(15);
    tv0.setText(" Sl.No ");
    tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    tv0.setLayoutParams(r1);
    tbrow0.addView(tv0);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);

    tv1.setTextSize(15);
    tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    tv1.setText(" Len ");
    //tv1.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv0.setLayoutParams(r1);
    tbrow0.addView(tv1);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);

    tv2.setTextSize(15);
    tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    tv2.setText(" Wid ");
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    //tv2.setPadding(10,5,10,5);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(r1);
    tbrow0.addView(tv2);

    TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);

    tv3.setTextSize(15);
    tv3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    tv3.setText(" Sq Ft ");
    //tv3.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv3.setLayoutParams(r1);
    tbrow0.addView(tv3);
    stk.addView(tbrow0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
        TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
        t1v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        t1v.setText("" + i);
        t1v.setTextSize(15);
        t1v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tbrow.addView(t1v);

        EditText t2v = new EditText(this);
        t2v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        //tv2.setHint("");
        //t2v.setText("Product " + i);
        //t2v.setTextSize(15);
        //t2v.setId(i);
        t2v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t2v.isClickable(true);

        tbrow.addView(t2v);

        EditText t3v = new EditText(this);
        t3v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        //t3v.setText("Rs." + i);
        t3v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t3v.setId(i+1);
        //t3v.setTextSize(15);
        tbrow.addView(t3v);

        TextView t4v = new TextView(this);
        t4v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        t4v.setText(""+calculation);
        t4v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t4v.setTextSize(15);
        tbrow.addView(t4v);
        stk.addView(tbrow);
        }
```

here is my xml file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_margin="9dp"
                android:id="@+id/table_main"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: iterate over edittexts then parse its content to integer like 
`Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString())`

Comment: @BasilBattikhi But then how will I pass that value to the sq ft cell?
I'm really new to android programming. I want to know how will I read value of len and wid and then multiply them and display result in the sq ft cell?

Comment: i prefer to see some android tutorial until you start with android

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I've tried a lot of tutorials and guides already but I'm not able to understand how to display the value in the sq.ft column as the user is entering the values in the len and width column as there will be multiple enteries by the user.

Comment: if you are unable to understand the tutorial then you have to understand java as first step  and if you don't have time go to hybrid platforms